# How to parse a million records of CSV with multiple cores using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, csv, event-loop

Currently I am trying to parse a CSV of million records or more by using csvtojson library to create a s3filestream and processing it line by line. While processing I convert it into a general format store and it in mongoDB.
The issue I am facing is that the entire process runs on single core. I've got a 8 core processor running. How can I use all of the cores to split the work and optimise the performance ?

Comment: You can create a pool of thread worker and write your worker logic there

Comment: Can you help me with that? Not sure how to work with worker threads

Comment: I just realized this lib has multi core support in v1. Have you taken a look at that?

Comment: Not yet ,gotta give it a shot.Though I can see its experimental.

Comment: The methods that I am using from that module aren't available in v1.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/). This is a command line tool installed with MongoDB that is purpose built to import CSV, TSV and raw JSON files. If you use the `--numInsertionWorkers=<int>` you can set the number of worker threads (8 would be recommended in your case).

Comment: I want to do it using the code. Command line would not ne suitable.

Comment: Split the CSV into 8 pieces. Assign processing thread per piece and process them in parallel. I wrote a splitter to do this a while ago https://github.com/jdrumgoole/pymongoimport/blob/master/pymongoimport/splitfile.py